# Why does the 1360 x 768 resolution mess up my display

Tags: nvidia, display, 16.10, display-resolution

Whenever I use my PC I prefer to use the best resolution possible. Which for windows is 900p and for my Ubuntu apparently is 1360 x 768. However whenever I change to this resolution my desktop is magnified and I am left with an unusable PC as in the screen shots:

[image: Screen shot of desktop]

Notice how the clock and the settings icon are missing from the menu bar at the top. Yes my monitor scales up the display at this resolution and shows only a portion of the screen. I have ascertained that the problem is not with my monitor by using the same resolution on windows Which works perfectly though it looks too bad. However as it is evident from the image it is a total mess in Ubuntu. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

**PC Specs:**

- Nvidia geforce 210 (Driver version 340)
- intel i3
- Intel DH61BF motherboard
- Ubuntu 16.10 with windows 10 dual boot

Comment: Resolution is OS independent and there's only one that should be used, the monitor's **native** resolution. If you can't use that in Ubuntu it means you don't have the proper graphics drivers and/or are using an analogue (D-SUB aka "VGA") connection.

Comment: @CelticWarrior. Yes I am using a VGA connection because there is no other connection interface to my monitor. In this case what should I do.

Comment: Please edit the question and add hardware specs, especially graphics, and Ubuntu release/version. Generally you would start with drivers: If Nvidia try the proprietary drivers; if others and 16.04 (or 14.04.5) or newer then you're already running the available drivers. Then there's `xrandr` that can add new modes (resolution and refresh rate) and will (hopefully) work in your case.